# How can I determine a first-time hit in WordPress?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

For analytics purposes, I need to determine if a user is a first time visitor, and output some JavaScript.

Preferably I'd be able to do this from the theme editor, not having to edit the code, but if that is the best way to achieve this, that's fine.

I was thinking something with the session, but it seems like I would have to hack some code for WordPress to use sessions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a plug-in exists that does what you are looking for if I understand your question correctly.

http://weblogtoolscollection.com/news/topic/wordpress-plugin-for-first-time-visitors

Answer (score 0):

This question reminded me the [What Would Seth Godin Do wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/what-would-seth-godin-do) which has been ported to many CMS and blogging tools.

Comment: figuring out who Seth Godin is, is left as an exercise to the reader :)

Comment: Seth Godin is what makes Chuck Norris jokes funny.